# Mootools Injecting new element

Tags: class, function, mootools, using, inject

I am trying to inject one element in the  div which have parent class . 
There is no  problem when i am injecting with the ID selector but once i try using  class selector it doesn't work..

```
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
    var FirstElement = new Element('div', {id: 'FirstElement',text:'test'});
    $('submit').addEvent('click',function(){                
        FirstElement.inject('parent');//working using ID selector               
        FirstElement.inject('div.parent');//not working using Class selector
    });
});
```

Here is html code

```
<div class="parent" id="parent"></div>
<input id='submit' value="submit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

replace with:

`FirstElement.inject(document.getElement('div.parent'));`

keep in mind this will return the first matching `div.parent` so if you have more than one, you need to anchor into the form like `this.getElement('div.parent')` where `this` is the form element